# The width of table can not larger than 100% when set width to auto in chrome 80?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, html-table, width

When I set width to auto;
In chrome 80, the width of the table is up to 100%.
In chrome 100+, the width of the table can larger then 100%.
I want to know what's the reason lead to this problem and how to resolve it.

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div style="overflow-x:auto">
  <table style="width:auto">
    <colgroup>
      <col style="width: 3000px; min-width: 3000px;">

    </colgroup>
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="background-color: red;color: black">
        1
      </th>

    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="background-color: red;color: black">
        1
      </td>

    </tr>
    </tbody>


  </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/tablesng/

Comment: @Alohci
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list?q=label%3ATarget-TablesNG&can=1
I found no change about width:auto in issues.

Answer (score 0):

Although replacing width: auto with width: max content has an effect. But I don't know the reason.

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div style="overflow-x:auto">
  <table style="width:max-content">
    <colgroup>
      <col style="width: 3000px; min-width: 3000px;">

    </colgroup>
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="background-color: red;color: black">
        1
      </th>

    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="background-color: red;color: black">
        1
      </td>

    </tr>
    </tbody>


  </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```